# How to tell ant apply task the destination

Tags: ant

Here is my ant apply task:

```
<apply executable="${7z.exec}" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="x"/>
  <fileset dir="${distdir}">
    <include name="**/*.zip"/>
  </fileset>
</apply>
```

7z.exec is an absolute path to the 7z.exe executable.  How can I tell 7zip to deposit the unzipped files into the same folder as the .zip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [7z `-o` switch for the eXtract command](https://superuser.com/questions/95902/7-zip-and-unzipping-from-command-line) and an Ant [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) to get just the path to the zip. The Ant [`apply` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) has a targetfile element that allows you extra flexibility in composing the command line for the task.  Leads to something like:

```
<apply executable="${7z.exec}" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="x"/>
  <srcfile />
  <targetfile prefix="-o" />
  <mapper type="regexp" from="^(.*)/(.*\.zip)" to="\1" />

  <fileset dir="${distdir}">
    <include name="**/*.zip"/>
  </fileset>
</apply>
```

Comment: This didn't work.  When I run my ant script, the apply task didn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry to hear that!  I suggest you run ant in verbose mode (-v command-line option) that will show you what command the apply task is trying to run.  If it is not running at all, then perhaps there is a fault in the fileset.  I'm not familiar with 7z, but perhaps the version you have doesn't have the -o option for the x command.  Let me know what you find, and I'll try to offer more advice.